# Split directory from string in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I guys,

I'm trying to split the directory of string like this:

```
val pwd = "travel/holiday/"
val listOfDirectory = pwd.split("/".toRegex())

output: "travel","holiday",""
```

Why is created a blank space in the last position? Also, How can I remove that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty string is there because you've got "/" after "holiday".
You can skip empty elements using 'filter' extension function like this:

```
val listOfDirectory = pwd.split("/").filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a trailing `/` in your string. The empty element is what follows the last `/`, which is nothing.

To drop the last item in a list you can use

```
val dropped = listOfDirectory.dropLast(1)
```

Also, you don't need the `.toRegex()` call in split in this example.